# Error TF255417 when using Standard Single Server wizard for TFS 2010

Tags: wss-3.0

"You specified a SharePoint Web application that has not been configured to grant access to Team Foundation Server.  In order to add this Web application, you must either have Farm Administrator permissions, or a farm administrator must have granted access to this deployment of Team Foundation Server."

Can anyone help me with a starting point to diagnose what the issue is here?  The wizard is installing WSS 3.0 and configuring it for me.  How can I set Farm Administrator permissions if WSS 3.0 doesn't exist?

The wizard only prompts me for one peice of information; a non-system account that will be used as both the TFS report reader account and the WSS 3.0 service account.

I am entering the details of a domain account that has been added to the local admnistrators group.

I have been struggling with this for hours now, trying all ways I can think of, but I still get this error every single time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the account running the service is granted the rights to logon as batch job in the local security policy. That was causing me the exact same problem when installing a couple of days ago.

Comment: Hmm, my server is in a domain so I'm going to have to wait for IT to do this for me it seems (as the "Add User or Group" button is inactive in local policy).  I will update when I can.

Comment: Actually, that's not going to be until late this evening so I'll accept your answer and re-raise if necessary later.  Thanks again :).

Comment: UPDATE:  That was it!  I owe you a drink :).  Hours upon hours of pain.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to be able to help out :D

Comment: I would be very interested to hear how you worked it out?  I thought I had literally scoured the installation documentation.

Comment: I noticed that when trying to go to the Sharepoint Central Admin I would allways get a Error 503 Service Not Available response. I also noticed that after the Sharepoint Central Admin app pool was not running in IIS. After starting the app pool it would stop again when trying to go to central admin again. So I started to look at the IIS event logs and there it was in plain text that the account need to be able to log on as a batch job.

Comment: Heh, I followed that exact same path apart from the all-important last step.  I will remember to check the IIS logs the next time I see HTTP errors.  Seems so obvious now.  Thank you for sharing :).